Next.JS MutationObserver does not trigger on shadowRoot
I have an external library I want to change an inner class CSS.
This library creates Shadow Root as following:
<external-lib ...>
   #shadow-root(open)
      <style>
         ...
      </style>
      <div class="change-me">
         ...
      </div>
</external-lib>

This is the code I wrote so far:
  useEffect(() => {
    const external_lib = document.querySelector('external-lib');
    
    const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
      const external_lib = document.querySelector('external-lib');

      alert("Observer Called");

      if (external_lib && external_lib.shadowRoot) {
        observer.disconnect();
        const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
        sheet.replaceSync(".change-me { color: red }");
        external_lib.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets.push(sheet);
      }
    });

    observer.observe(external_lib!, { subtree: true, childList: true, attributes: true, characterData: true });
  });

Unfortunately, the observer is never triggered and the external_lib.shadowRoot always result as null.
alert("Observer Called"); is never reached.
How can I make the observer get triggered on shadowRoot changes?

Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet with the [< >] button in the editor. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Where is the code that triggers that Mutation Observer?

There is no code which triggers it, as far as I understood, it listen for DOM changes and get triggered by them, am I wrong?

You need to trigger changes in DOM for elements you assigned Mutation Observer is is listening on.. Take your code apart, learn it step by step.
